# got the error "This project uses Meteor 1.2.1, which isn't available on Windows." with one user and not with another

Tags: windows, meteor

I have two different users on my professionnal laptop, one for work, the other for personnal use.
I have a meteor project that I can run without problem with my work user. But when I try running it with my personnal user, I get this error :

```
This project uses Meteor 1.2.1, which isn't available on Windows. To work with this app on 
all supported platforms, use meteor update --release METEOR@1.2.1 to pin this app to the 
newest Windows-compatible release.
```

I read about such problem when trying to run on different OS, but nothing with two users on the same system.

Comment: what happens when you run meteor update --release METEOR@1.2.1?

Comment: I get exactly the same error.

Comment: seems like a bug.. you might want to raise this as an issue on github within meteor repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get the solution.
My work user is a domain user and I installed Meteor with this one. I just uninstalled Meteor and reinstalled it with my personal user and it worked fine now.